# Should I forego fajr prayer when my husband asks for intercourse?

Tags: salat, sex, husband-wife

I'm newly married and I never left off any prayer but when my husband ask me for intercourse, I have to let go of my fajr prayer, what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

### Sex or Salah?    Salah

---

Failing to pray salah and delaying them until their time is over is a **major sin.**

Allah says in the Qu'ran:

> “Verily, as‑salah (the formal prayer) is enjoined on the believers at fixed hours.”
>
> ([al-Nisa 4:103](https://quran.com/4/103))

He also says:

> “‘What has caused you to enter Hell?’
>
> They will say: ‘We were not of those who used to offer the salah (prayers).’”
>
> ([al-Muddaththir 74:42-43](https://quran.com/74/42-43))

The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) said:

> “The covenant that stands between us and them is prayer; whoever gives up prayer is a kafir (disbeliever).”
>
> Narrated by al-Tirmidhi, 2621; al-Nasai, 431; Ibn Majah, 1079. Classed as saheeh (authentic) by al-Albani in Saheeh al-Tirmidhi, 2113.

The above verses and hadith clearly state that missing/ignoring salah is a **major sin**.

The one who does that habitually and takes the matter lightly is in grave danger. It will lead to his doom in the Hereafter and to his being a loser before Allaah.

---

You should tell your husband this and that you should arrange another time to have sexual activity preferably after salah.

If he doesn't listen to you and rapes you, then he is commiting a sin in sharia law and you are **not permitted** to have sexual activity with him and you are not sinning.

Pray to Allah to help you.

And Allah knows best.

---

Source: [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/104018)